# "cannot return value referencing local variable" when returning PhysicalDevice (Vulkano)

Tags: rust, ownership

I know this is a Rust newbie problem, but I actually can't wrap my head around it. I need to pass around a `PhysicalDevice` from the Vulkano library. The problem is, `PhysicalDevice` holds a reference:

```rs
pub struct PhysicalDevice<'a> {
    instance: &'a Arc<Instance>,
    device: usize,
}
```

So Rust won't compile my sacred code:

```rs
struct InstanceInfo<'a> {
    instance: Arc<Instance>,
    physical: PhysicalDevice<'a>,
    // ...
}

// ...

fn instantiate() -> InstanceInfo<'static> {
    // ...
    let instance = Instance::new(None, &required_extensions, None).unwrap();
    
    let physical = PhysicalDevice::enumerate(&instance).next().unwrap();
    // ...
    InstanceInfo { // cannot return value referencing local blah
        instance,
        physical,
        // ...
    }
}
```

How can I work around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the reason for the error message is that `instance` is a local variable in your `instantiate` function. Because you aren't moving its ownership to the return value, it will be dropped at the end of the function.

But then if it gets dropped, any reference to it would be invalid. That's why Rust doesn't let you return something holding a reference to the local variable.

First, your struct is redundant, because `PhysicalDevice` already holds a reference for the instance. Even without the local variable problem, I think you'd run into an ownership problem.

Second, let's say you rewrite and get rid of your `InstanceInfo` struct and instead you want to just return a `PhysicalDevice<'static>`. Well if that's what you promise to the compiler, then you have to make sure that the `instance` you create will live for as long as the program lives.

You can do that either by having `instance` be a static variable of your module, or by creating it at the very beginning of the program and then simply pass a reference ot it around.

For example

```
fn main() {
 let instance = Instance::new(None, blablabla).unwrap();
 
 let physical = instantiate(&instance);
}

fn instantiate<'a>(instance: &'a Arc<Instance>) -> PhysicalDevice<'a> {
  PhysicalDevice::enumerate(instance).next().unwrap();
}
```

Might have gotten a `&` wrong here or there, but this is the gist of it.

If you *have* to put everything into an extra struct, then I think what you want to do is to `clone` the `Arc` instead of just moving it.

Comment: Thank you! I did still need the struct because I have other fields, but the latter solution worked.